# Spring batch Task executor

Tags: spring-boot, spring-batch

I found below config and statement on spring batch scaling and parallel documentation-

```
@Bean
public TaskExecutor taskExecutor() {
    return new SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor("spring_batch");
}

@Bean
public Step sampleStep(TaskExecutor taskExecutor, JobRepository jobRepository, PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager) {
    return new StepBuilder("sampleStep", jobRepository)
                .<String, String>chunk(10, transactionManager)
                .reader(itemReader())
                .writer(itemWriter())
                .taskExecutor(taskExecutor)
                .build();
}
```

Statement - The result of the preceding configuration is that the Step executes by reading, processing, and writing each chunk of items (each commit interval) in a separate thread of execution.

So my question is - I am confused here little bit that here chunks will execute parallely like suppose if I've 5 chunks of 10 items so is 5 chunks will execute parallely or the 10 items inside one chunk will execute in multithreaded way?

Answer (score 0):

> So my question is - I am confused here little bit that here chunks will execute parallely like suppose if I've 5 chunks of 10 items so is 5 chunks will execute parallely or the 10 items inside one chunk will execute in multithreaded way?

What the documentation means is that chunks will be processed concurrently, not parallelly. Items will be read, processed and written concurrently by different threads.

Chunks are processed in parallel in a remote chunking setup in which the idea is the following: chunks are created by a single reader, wrapped in `ChunkRequest`s which are sent over the wire to be processed by different workers in parallel (ie each worker is processing a different chunk in parallel at the same time as other workers). That's parallelism.